# Change Parse Client Key

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, server

We have a website and iOS app and an Android app that are running against a Parse backend. We would like to keep the website running but disable the apps by preventing API requests from them.

I am thinking that the simplest way to do this may be to change the Parse API keys. I have tried resetting the Parse master key on a test app and this does not seem to alter the client API key. Is there any way to do this? It doesn't matter if the JS key is also altered, as we can update the website to reflect this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone your Parse app, all settings will be moved to the new app and new keys will be generated.

Also you can copy data in new app. Just export it from old one and import to the copied one.